# Force dynamic div's to be on the same line

Tags: css, html

Hey guys i really need some help here:)

my problem is that i got 2 dynamic width div's inside a div, they go from 460 to 640px (just an example) and my site spands from 960px to 1300px, so when my site is 1300px wide i want both div's to be on the same line with a width of 640px, and when the site is 960px i want the div's to be on the same line with a width of 460px.

my problem is that, when the sites get smaller (dragging the width of the browser), they drop below each other.

here is some code: http://jsfiddle.net/EKYLe/2/

Here is the html:

```
<div class="Content">
<div class="box-container">
    <div class="box">
        <h2>Nyheder</h2>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>

    <ul>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <h2>Nyheder</h2>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>

    <ul>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

as you can see when u move the size of the windows they drop blow each other.

regards Nicklas

Comment: They stay in place for me. Is this browser specific?

Comment: Seems fine in Firefox, what browser you using?

Comment: im using Firefox. try move the center line from left to right

Comment: then you will see they drop under each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to control their position, you should put them inside a table. That way they always will remain in column 1 and column 2 of the tablerow. And you can align them inside the page without much trouble.